# AsyncTask как отдельный класс

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-asynctask

Здравствуйте!

Помогите найти урок или поясните возможность реализации класса, наследующего AsyncTask как самостоятельного, а не в теле другого. И возможно ли это?

Comment: Элементарно создать отдельный класс и конструктор, в который передавать контекст

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[@ЮрийСПб](/users/17609/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B1), [@Kvazio](/users/24798/kvazio) вот вам пример с листненерами(callback), а [@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf) прав, так правильно.

```
public class Foo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MyCustomCallBack callback;

    public Foo(final MyCustomCallBack callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // do what you want

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(callback!=null)
            callback.doSomething(result);
    }

    public interface MyCustomCallBack
    {
        public void doSomething(Void someResult);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Foo.MyCustomCallBack
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Foo foo = new Foo(this);
        foo.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(Void someResult)
    {
        //этот метод вызовется, когда у asynctask'а вызовется метод onPostExecute
    }
}
```

Comment: ога, и если повернуть экран, разве не будет memory leak активити(реализующего листенер)?

Comment: @Andreich, отличный пример, спасибо!

Comment: @gcoder будет. Поэтому не надо вообще использовать асинктаски. 
Либо запретить активити пересоздаваться при повороте экрана.

Comment: Я их и не использую почти никогда, потому что так и не понял, как их верно использовать, либо слишком много кода/работы возиться с ними.

Comment: @gcoder да, правильно. К слову, лоадеры(loaders) тоже текут.  :)  
Я использую сервисы.

Comment: Спасибо за легкий и понятный ответ!

Comment: @Andreich, раз уж пошла такая пьянка... А в сервисах как правильно делать? Я нынче по алармМенеджеру запускаю сервис, а в нём асинктаск, коий по завершении нотификацию к статус бар кидает... 
Это совсем плохо? Я не пробовал в интернеты лазить прямо из сервиса - может так и надо?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не заметил комментария. Я использую Robospice.  Он реализован полностью на сервисах.
https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice    
А вообще советую почитать вот эту статейку, очень полезно http://derevyanko.blogspot.ru/2014/01/rest-android-1.html

Comment: @Andreich, та же беда( Спасибо за ссылки - бегло посмотрел - вроде как должно мне пригодится в плане замены своих велосипедов)

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, привожу Вам полный код, редактируйте по своему усмотрению.

```
public class Foo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private String mName;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public Foo(TextView textView, String name) {
        super();

        mTextView = textView;
        mName = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // do what you want

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mTextView.setText(mName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Передавать в AsyncTask ссылку на GUI элемент - плохой тон. Туда надо передавать listener'а и его дёргать в onPostExecute.

Comment: Более подробно?

Comment: @Suvitruf, я думаю, если человек спросил, как вообще от класса наследоваться, ему сейчас не до callback'ов с listener'ами.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit я думаю, если человек с этим не работал, то надо давать сразу правильные примеры.

Comment: @Suvitruf, да, если не сложно, дайте нам кратчайший пример с листенером.

Comment: Добавить интерфейс, реализовать и передать ссылку. Это пара строк кода. Не надо ёрничать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, да никто и не ёрничает. Есть люди, которые всерьёз этого не знают. Я, например. И простейший пример мне бы очень пригодился. Тем более, что вы утверждаете, что это будет правильнее, чем вышеприведённый ответ.

Comment: @Kvazio, если ответ Вас удовлетворил, отметьте его, пожалуйста.