# Как вынести обновление формы в onPostExecute из doInBackground

Tags: java, android

Я хочу вынести из главного потока получение информации о маршруте и отправить инфу в onPostExecute и там в главном потоке обновить форму но у меня не получается

```
package com.ftg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class EditRouteActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editRoute_name;
    EditText editRoute_desc;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;
    Button btnPhoto;
    Button btnMap;


    String route_id;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> routeprList;
    HashMap<String, String> mapa;

    // url для получения одного маршрута
    private static final String url_route_detials = "http://172.16.0.100/route_get_details.php";

    // url для обновления маршрута
    private static final String url_update_route = "http://172.16.0.100/route_update.php";

    // url для удаления маршрута
    private static final String url_delete_route = "http://172.16.0.100/route_delete.php";

    // JSON параметры
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE = "route";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_ID = "route_id";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_NAME = "route_name";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION = "route_description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_route);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
        btnMap =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);

        // показываем форму про детальную информацию о маршруте
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // получаем id маршрута (route_id) с формы
        route_id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ROUTE_ID);

        routeprList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Получение полной информации о маршруте в фоновом потоке
        new GetRouteDetails().execute();

        // обрабочик на кнопку сохранение маршрута
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // запускаем выполнение задачи на обновление маршрута
                new SaveRouteDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // обработчик на кнопку удаление маршрута
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // удалем маршрут в фоновом потоке
                new DeleteRoute().execute();
            }
        });
        btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreatePhotoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GmapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Фоновая асинхронная задача для получения полной информации о маршруте
     **/
    class GetRouteDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Перед началом показать в фоновом потоке прогресс диалог
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading route details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Получение детальной информации о продукте в фоновом режиме
         **/
        protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
            // Список параметров
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route_id", route_id));

            // получаем продукт по HTTP запросу
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_route_detials, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Single Route Details", json.toString());
                    try {

                      int  success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // Успешно получена детальная информация о маршруте
                            JSONArray routeObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ROUTE);

                            // получаем первый обьект с JSON Array
                            JSONObject route = routeObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            String route_name = route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_NAME);
                            String route_description = route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION);



                            HashMap<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение

                            mapa.put(TAG_ROUTE_NAME, route_name);
                            mapa.put(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION, route_description);
                            // добавляем HashList в ArrayList


                            routeprList.add(mapa);


                        }else{
                            // продукт с route_id не найден
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        }
    }).start();
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем диалог прогресс
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // закрываем диалог прогресс
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                     * */
                    // продукт с route_id найден
                    // Edit Text
            editRoute_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_name);
            editRoute_desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_desc);

                    // покаываем данные о продукте в EditText

                    editRoute_name.setText(mapa.get(TAG_ROUTE_NAME));
                    editRoute_desc.setText(mapa.get(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION));
                }
            });
        }
    }

/**
 * В фоновом режиме выполняем асинхроную задачу на сохранение маршрута
 **/
class SaveRouteDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом показываем в фоновом потоке прогрксс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving route ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем маршрут
     **/
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {
        // получаем обновленные данные с EditTexts
        String route_name = editRoute_name.getText().toString();
        String route_description = editRoute_desc.getText().toString();

        // формируем параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_ID, route_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_NAME, route_name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION, route_description));

        // отправляем измененные данные через http запрос
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_route, "POST", params);

        // проверяем json success тег
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // продукт удачно обнавлён
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // отправляем результирующий код 100 чтобы сообщить об обновлении продукта
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // продукт не обновлен
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После окончания закрываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Фоновая асинхронная задача на удаление продукта
 **/
class DeleteRoute extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * На начале показываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("УДАЛЕМ МАРШРУТ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Удаление продукта
     **/
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {

        int success;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route_id", route_id));

            // получение продукта используя HTTP запрос
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_route, "POST", params);

            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // Продукт удачно удален
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // отправляем результирующий код 100 для уведомления об удалении продукта
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После оконачния скрываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

вот мой лог

> 06-12 15:20:39.499: W/dalvikvm(4343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3a1f8)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343): java.lang.NullPointerException
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at com.ftg.EditRouteActivity$GetRouteDetails$2.run(EditRouteActivity.java:210)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4170)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at com.ftg.EditRouteActivity$GetRouteDetails.onPostExecute(EditRouteActivity.java:198)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at com.ftg.EditRouteActivity$GetRouteDetails.onPostExecute(EditRouteActivity.java:1)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>       06-12 15:20:39.519: E/AndroidRuntime(4343):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Где-то ещё, кроме метода `doInBackground()`, объявлена переменная `mapa`?

Comment: В class EditRouteActivity

Comment: я полный код выложил

Comment: А где падает? Кстати, зачем thread() внутри doInBackground, который и так в отдельном потоке всегда? Так же в onPostExecute() не надо вызывать runOnUiThread(), так как он всегда в main выполнится.

Comment: падает после получения json

Comment: @madcrack4 json == null ?

Comment: нет json приходит полный,
а если убираю thread то начинает ругаться на params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас много лишнего, вызванного непониманием того, как работает [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

1. Выполнение кода в doInBackground в отдельном потоке излишне. Всё, выполняемое в doInBackground УЖЕ в отдельном потоке.
2. Также лишнее runOnUiThread в onPostExecute ибо код тут УЖЕ выполняется в основном потоке (т.е. в UiThread).
3. NPE у вас из-за того, что вы не инициализировали переменную. Вам надо передать (например) Map в конструктор задачи, заполнить её в doInBackground и после в onPostExecute уже работать с UI.

Comment: то-есть я убираю new "Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {}"
и в onPostExecute убираю  "runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {public void run() {}" 
а что значит передать map в конструктор задачи?

Comment: то есть class GetRouteDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap>?

Comment: В целом да. AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap> и doInBackground должен иметь тип HashMap. В onPostExecute в аргументе тоже HashMap. При этом, если вы передадите активити в конструктор то сможете её переменной присвоить полученный HashMap. Но лучше пользовать коллбэк. Посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/373522/17609