# AsyncTask вернуть результат

Tags: android

Скажите, пожалуйста, как дождаться выполнения AsyncTask, есть класс с описанным ниже содержанием, вызываю его из другого Activity - `new Organizer().getOrganizerID(ctx, h.author)`, но не получается дождаться выполнения и получить данные... Что я делаю не так?

```
public class Organizer {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String orgId;

    public String getOrganizerID(Context context, String param1) {
        String b = "0";
        try {
        b = new getOrganizerID(context, param1).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }

    private class getOrganizerID extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String id;

        public getOrganizerID(Context context, String param1) {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_processing));
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_receiving_data));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // тут получаю, с помошью jsoup данные и сохраняю их в id
        }

        protected String onPostExecute() {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код вообще запускается? Тут есть множество явных ошибок. UPD: а, понял. Он запускается, поскольку onPreExecute и onPostExecute просто ничего не оверрайдят, да. Ну, сейчас попробую ответить.

Comment: @ДаниярСупиев вот ещё ссылку в ответ добавьте (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/373522/17609) - она поможет объяснить на примере.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, вся суть AsyncTask в том и заключается, что он избавляет от необходимости останавливать UI-тред (тот, который обрабатывает всё взаимодействие с пользователем, от обработки нажатий на кнопки до анимации). А вызов get без уверенности, что операция завершена приведёт как раз к остановке UI-треда, и к "подвисанию" приложения на время пока ответ не будет получен. Поэтому сам подход некорректен.

Во-вторых, нужно всегда помнить, что сам по себе AsyncTask ничего не возвращает, и поэтому делать `protected String onPostExecute` смысла нет.

В-третьих, чисто стилистическое замечание: не называйте классы так же, как и методы. Язык, конечно, позволяет так поступать, но делать так — дурной тон.

Как же быть? Возможно, я чего-то не знаю о требовании к данному методу, но по тому, что я вижу, могу предположить, что просто требуется вернуть некое значение. Если это так — то всё довольно-таки просто.

```
private class OrganizerIDRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private String param1;
    private String context;

    public OrganizerIdRequest(Context context, String param1) {
        // Это — конструктор. Он просто создаёт объект данного
        // класса. Исполнение запроса не начнётся, пока ты не
        // вызовешь execute.
        this.param1 = param1;
        // Я решил записать параметры
        // конструктора на всякий случай. Кстати, зачем тебе param1?
        // Если он не используется в doInBackground, то он тут
        //лишний.
        this.context = context;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
        // Здесь находится то, что должно исполниться до того, как
        // начнётся основная работа. Например, вывод уведомления о
        // том, что пользователю следует подождать
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_processing));
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_receiving_data));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // тут у тебя обязательно в конце должен быть return,
        // отдающий String с тем значением, которое тебе нужно.
        // Почему именно String? Потому что ты его указал в
        // <Void, Void, String>
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Обрати внимание, что данный метод ничего не должен
        // возвращать. Он обязательно должен быть void. Зато он
        // получает в качестве аргумента ответ, который посылает
        // doInBackground. И тут ты можешь сделать с ним что твоей
        // душе угодно. В твоём случае тебе с ним делать ничего не
        // надо, но на будущее запомни.
        super.onPostExecute(result); // это ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО нужно сделать, иначе
        // .get() не вернёт ничего, поскольку ни о каком результате понятия
        // иметь не будет.
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Так должен выглядеть класс, отправляющий запрос. Теперь разберёмся с тем, каким образом нужно передавать значение куда-то ещё. Вешать главный тред пока не придёт ответ — это очень плохо. Но пока пройдёмся по твоему варианту. Для по-настоящему хорошей реализации тебе нужно будет почитать про Runnable и Handler. Тогда ты сможешь делать красивые загрузчики и ожидалки.

```
public class Organizer {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String orgId;

    public String getOrganizerID(Context context, String param1) {
        OrganizerIdRequest r = new OrganizerIdRequest(context, param1).execute();
        // Обрати внимание на execute. Пока ты его не вызовешь, запрос не
        // начнёт исполняться. Можешь, конечно, запихать его вызов в конструктор
        // объекта, это поможет. Но, по-хорошему, сюда нужно передавать
        // те параметры, которые нужны для формирования запроса, поэтому
        // делать так можно только в том случае, если запрос не имеет
        // никаких специфичных параметров.
        try {
            return r.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "0";
    }
```

По идее, это должно сработать, хотя я не тестил.

Можешь почитать ссылку, которую @ЮрийСПБ кинул в комменты, но только после того, как хорошенько разберёшься в том, как работает AsyncTask.

Если что, пиши в комментах об ошибках. Постараюсь исправить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за детальное описание. Не ожидал, честно, что так быстро и в таком отличном качестве ответят и укажут на мои ошибки. Буду пробовать! Это мое первое приложение и бывают ступоры, конкретные по логике.

Comment: Красивые загрузчики уже написаны. Loader<D>, AsyncTaskLoader<D>, CursorLoader.