# AsyncTask ожидание завершения потока.

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-sdk, android-asynctask

Добрый день.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Ниже код который не работает, хотя должен. Приложение вылетает без каких либо ошибок. 
Если mResultChekc = 1; переношу из метода onPostExecute() в метод doInBackground() перед bufferedReader.close(); то все работает. Хотя везде пишут что окончанием AsyncTask является выполнение onPostExecute() и в нем нужно выставлять переменную об окончании.

Еще приложение вылетает если вместо  String mString использовать StringBuilder. После выполнения строчки mString.append(line) в цикле.

Есть класс унаследованный от AsyncTask :

```
public class DownloadCountry extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    private String mString;
    public int mResultChekc = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Подключаемся к сайту и скачиваем содержимое
        try {
            URL pageURL = new URL("https:хххххх.com");
            URLConnection urlConnection = pageURL.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line =  null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                mString = line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        // Сообщаем о том что все действия выполнены.
        mResultChekc = 1;

    }
}
```

И другой класс который ждет его выполнения:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.SplashTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Запускаем поток для скачивания
        // Ждем когда он выполнится и переходим на Мain
        DownloadCountry dc = new DownloadCountry();
        dc.execute();
        while (true){
            if (dc.mResultChekc == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас падает приложение по ANR (ApplicationNotResponded) из-за того, что вы заморозили основной поток более чем на 5 секунд.

Вы изначально выбрали неверный подход. Вместо ожидания завершения асинхронной задачи в бесконечном цикле основного потока вам надо дождаться её завершения и вызова метода onPostExecute - и именно из-него выполнить код.

Если класс задачи не описан в классе активити, то вы можете в задаче создать интерфейс, реализовать его в активити и передать в задачу активити через конструктор задачи. После чего в onPostExecute вызвать метод интерфейса.

Так у вас выполнится код из активити после завершения задачи и без заморозки главного потока.

А вообще - AsyncTask устарел и его уже не используют, т.к. с ним много проблем. Но, думаю, советовать вам RxJava пока рано, хотя можете попробовать

Comment: RxJava - это интересно, но пока бы с AsyncTask разобраться бы. Если вылетает ANR то как правильно реализовать работу? Можете пояснить что вы имели ввиду : _Если класс задачи не описан в классе активити, то вы можете в задаче создать интерфейс, реализовать его в активити и передать в задачу активити через конструктор задачи. После чего в onPostExecute вызвать метод интерфейса._ ?

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов, вот тут пример того как надо с AsyncTask-ом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/373522/17609

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что надо, теперь все работает.

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов, если мой ответ вам помог вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: `Rx` огромная библиотека...